# I want to get the count of Childnodes selected in a node, including the sub directories

Tags: c#, treeview

I have recursive program to add the nodes t treeview but i want to have bottom-up approach to do this.

I have done this so far, but it is not working

```cs
private void TreeviewCountCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection treeNodeCollection)
{
    TreeNode node = treeNodeCollection[0];
    int countchecked = 0;
    if (node != null)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode childnode in node.Nodes)
        {
            if (childnode.Nodes.Count == 0 && childnode.Checked)
            {
                countchecked++;
            }
            else if (childnode.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                TreeviewCountCheckedNodes(childnode.Nodes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. [Can you please edit the question to reflect what you have tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: please add the programming language as a `Tag` to get code highlighting

Comment: @Simulant Did _not_ know that, neat.

Comment: "this is not working" -- what doesn't it do?

Comment: I am new to recursive programming, I am not getting how do i accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int TreeviewCountCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection treeNodeCollection)
        {
            int countchecked = 0;
            if (treeNodeCollection != null)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in treeNodeCollection)
                {
                    if (node.Nodes.Count == 0 && node.Checked)
                    {
                        countchecked++;
                    }
                    else if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        countchecked += TreeviewCountCheckedNodes(node.Nodes);
                    }
                }
            }
            return countchecked;
        }
```

Call:

```
int coount = TreeviewCountCheckedNodes(treeView.Nodes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response! The count is getting reset to 0 in every recursion call, But i want to have the count in subdirectories as well.

Comment: this will count all checked leafs of a treeview. do you mean you want to include checked subnodes in the result too?

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this code here thinking that it may help someone.

The code retrieves the count of all check nodes in a tree view.

```
int checkedNodesCount = 0;

private int GetCheckedNodesCount(TreeNodeCollection treeNodeCollection)
    {

        TreeNode node = treeNodeCollection[0];


        if (node != null)
        {
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode childnode in node.Nodes)
                {
                    if (childnode.Nodes.Count == 0 && childnode.Checked)
                    {
                        checkedNodesCount++;
                    }
                    else if (childnode.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        checkedNodesCount += GetCheckedNodesCount(childnode.Nodes);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    checkedNodesCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        return checkedNodesCount;
    }
```